# How do you set up a second database connection without the use of any yaml files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, heroku, multiple-databases

I have an app running on Heroku and I want to set up a connection to a second database (from another app running on Heroku). All solutions I have seen for multiple DBs involve the database.yml file, but Heroku does not do things this way, they instructed me to use `DATABASE_URL` from one app in the other.

I think I need to do something like:

```
DatabaseName::Base.establish_connection(DATABASE_URL)
```

and then I can use

```
establish_connection :DatabaseName
```

in the appropriate models. Where do I put

```
DatabaseName::Base.establish_connection(DATABASE_URL)
```

to have it available to all models? environment.rb? And what is the correct syntax for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have two dbs DBOne and DBTwo which you want to connect (please fill up the data accordingly). Hope that helps.

```
   class DBOne < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.abstract_class = true
    establish_connection(
      :adapter  => "mysql",
      :host     => "hostname",
      :username => "myuser",
      :password => "mypass",
      :database => "database_one"
    )
    end

    class ModelInDbOne <DBOne
    end

    class DBTwo < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.abstract_class = true
    establish_connection(
      :adapter  => "mysql",
      :host     => "hostname",
      :username => "myuser",
      :password => "mypass",
      :database => "database_two"
    )
    end 

    class ModelInDbTwo < DBTwo
    end
```

Comment: When I test this, it looks like it is setting up a link with "DBOne" as a table in "database_one" instead of as a connection to it.

Comment: Have you tried creating the the DBs and models with some data?.

Comment: It is giving me a "database_one"."DBone" table does not exist.

Comment: Sorry I missed a line "self.abstract_class = true" in DBOne and DBTwo. Will edit the answer.

Comment: We're definitely getting closer, but the connection is now to the last one declared whether I say "model < dbone" or "model < dbtwo".  It works perfectly if I declare the establish_connection individually in each model, but that surely is not the right answer.

Comment: Also, how will this (if at all) affect rake?

Comment: I just edited and tested it once again, removed "ActiveRecord::Base.". It worked fine for me. This should not affect rake in anyway.

Comment: That nailed it.  Thank You :-D